# Ctools content type- How do I access a context that is provided by a panel page?

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I'm trying to add a ctools custom content type to the *user profile* override provided by panels.

I have added a context, *Logged-in user*.  I can access the values of this variable in my custom content type like this:

```
dpm($context['context_user_1']);
```

However, I also want to access the values for *user-being-viewed*, which is available in the *user profile* page by default.  With the devel module, I can see the variables are in `$context` under `argument_entity_id:user1`, but I can't access them like this:

```
dpm($context['argument_entity_id:user1']);
```

How can I access the variables of a context provided by default in Panels?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way, but here's what I came up with:

```
$user = reset($context);
$user = $user->data;
```